# integrate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx=1$ between $-1$ and $1$.

Tags: logarithms, substitution, integration-by-parts

Mathematica tells me that
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{2}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx=1.$$

But I can't figure out how to do the integral by hand.

Would anyone care to give me a hand?

Comment: Probably a good start is rewriting $\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x} = \ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)$.

Comment: You could then do an integration method that would reduce the $x$ term to a constant. If you see where I'm going

Comment: Mathematica gives you a step-by-step solution if in the input you start by typing "=" twice

Comment: Coolwater:  When I type ==Integrate[(x/2)*Log[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}] Mathematica gives me the symbolic interpretation of the expression and a plot, but not step-by-step solution. I'm using ver 11.1.1.0 for the Mac--maybe this version isn't as helpful.
But it's nice to see what it does show me.

Comment: @JamesN I see, it only does when you integrate indefinitely `==Integrate[(x/2)*Log[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], x]`

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x):=x ln(1+x).$

What you have to establish is that $\int_{-1}^1 (f(x)+f(-x))dx=2$

It suffices then to find an antiderivative to $f$.

It is : $F(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1}{2}\ln(x+1)-\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{x}{2}$

Explanation

- Begin by a change of variable $u=x+1$, then $f(x)$ becomes $\varphi(u)=(u-1)\ln(u)=u \ln(u) - 1\ln(u)$
- Then integrate by parts.

In fact, one can easily find back that a primitive function of $x^n \ln(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\left(x^{n+1}\ln(x)-\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right).$

**Remark:** do you know that the function under the integral sign is $x ArcTanh(x) $ ?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that.  Thanks for the insight.